# Why Amazon Elastic Beanstalk takes a long time to update my deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Amazon EB. with (Puma, Nginx) 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.9 running Ruby 2.1 (Puma).

**Suddenly** when I deployed my project send the next error in my terminal:
**ERROR: Timed out while waiting for command to Complete**

***Note: Before didn't happen.***

I see the event in the console and this is the log:
**Update environment operation is complete, but with command timeouts. Try increasing the timeout period. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.**

I'v already incrementing the time without success.

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
    option_name: Timeout
    value: 1800
```

The Health takes a long time to put it in green (aprox, 20 min), and then it takes other long time for updating the instance with the new changes (aprox, other 20 min), (I have only one instance).

How can I see other logs?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like  rather common problem with elasticbeanstalk. In short your EC2 instance is going haywired. What you can do is to terminate the EC2 instance on the EC2 dashboard and the loader balancer will start new instance and that may save your problem. To minimise any down time you may start the new instance first and then terminate your older instance. Just be wary that you will lose any ephemeral data and you may have to reinstall certain dependencies (if they are not in your ebextensions 0

Let me know if you need any more help. Do check out the aws ebs forum

Cheers,
biobirdman

Comment: Hi, I've already try that solution but it follow with the problem, I've notice that the next command takes a long time (20 min), this is: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/11_asset_compilation.sh] : Starting activity...

Comment: No too sure why, try asking the folks at aws forums

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the RAM in the instance, so I had to change that instance by other bigger.